# Changing brightness/contrast of image file in Java based on sound.

Tags: java, audio, brightness

I was wondering if anyone has ever attempted to changed the brightness or contrast of an image file opened in java based on the output of some audio.

For example, I am currently having a java program playback some audio and at the same time create a window with an image of a bright light. I want the image of the bright light to darken or brighten based on the frequencies of the audio output from my computer or, if its easier, just based on the volume levels of the output. I am completely new to working with sound in Java, and so I am a bit stuck.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Here's the best example of the idea of the brightness changing with audio (look at the light on the mouth of the purple suited person and how it changes when she speaks): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xy9GYGFKpOw

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9860117/418556).  The last bullet point mentions the RMS level used for the stereo volume bars.  To do frequency analysis, look to an FFT.  *"so I am a bit stuck"*  You have a steep learning curve ahead.

Comment: I have some experience with FFTs and things related (used em in Matlab) but its not my cup of tea. I guess I can't avoid them. Thank you for the response.